# Using CreateSQLQuery with INSERT query in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

What is the state of the object, if it is added with using INSERT query? And how i can get this object same session?

Insert Object using native SQL

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)").ExecuteUpdate())
```

I know his Id, so using this for get:

```
sessison.Get<MyObjectType>(id)
```

but object is null, because the session is same and commit is still pending.
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Using CreateSQLQuery need, because my child object foo created based on his parent bar, but bar and foo have same Id, and used Table Per Concrete Class

Comment: This does not look normal to me. At raw SQL level, we can read uncommitted data on any isolation level provided we are reading withing the transaction having the data pending. Checking `ExecuteUpdate`, it is supposed to send the query immediately to db. May you check that in your case with a profiler? Then the `Get` should be able to find your new entity, unless you are in some specific case, like having a stale entity with the same Id in your session but marked for deletion. Enable NHibernate debug log4net logs, and logs from `DefaultLoadEventListener`should give you details.

Comment: No, after ExecuteUpdate, profiler say, that i', just send Insert, but no commit. I think it depends on ISessionProvider Life style

Comment: Just sending the insert was what I was expecting to see in profiler. Anyway, your comment [here](/questions/36386613/using-createsqlquery-with-insert-query-in-nhibernate?noredirect=1#comment60434278_36388601) tells you have found something, you should probably add it as an answer to your own question, and accept it. Or if you do not understand why your change cause your code to work, maybe should you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

In my case, `ISessionProvider` have Life style - `perWebRequest`. This means that session be commited  after the end web request.

Next. After insert, we have no entity, but we can merge new entity, created based on data for insert, with current session.

```
session.Merge(new Entity(...));
```

or if you have parent entity in `Persistence Context`, you need do so:

```
session.Evict(parentEntity);
session.Merge(new Entity(...));
```

`Evict` remove entity with some id (child and parent have some id), else you will get an exception.
This will merge entity with current session, and when you use `sessison.Get<MyObjectType>(entityId)` object doesn't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Either commit the first transaction before attempting the `.Get` or you might be able to use `.Load` instead if you only need to associate this entity with another entity before an update or insert.

Writing raw sql queries will not save things in session as you are not dealing with entities.

Comment: I am a bit surprised. Aren't we supposed to be able to read data added in current pending transaction, if we are reading within this same transaction? Normally we should not need committing the transaction. Does the `ExecuteUpdate` actually execute only on `Flush`? (If this was an SQL update case on already loaded entities, we would need to evict entities from the session though.)

Comment: It depends what transaction isolation level you are using  when reading data.  You would have to explicitly set it to read uncommitted data to do this and this is assuming the update/insert has actually been sent to the database in a transaction that is still pending.

Comment: You get me doubting, but testing in read committed `begin tran; insert Parametre (Code) values ('test'); select * from parametre; rollback; select * from parametre;` yields one result less on second case, meaning we do not need read uncommitted for reading pending data, provided we are still in the same transaction. And on an insert case, I do not see why NHibernate first level cache could interfere.

Comment: In my case, the simplest solution was to use merge. But, thanks you.